# Fibered categories, introduction or notes

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, grothendieck-topologies

I would like to learn about fibered categories, I know basic category theory, but not algebraic geometry.
Is there a text, or lecture notes, which motivate the definitions from fields other than algebraic geometry?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1812490/in-category-theory-what-is-a-fibration-and-why-should-i-care-about-them

Answer (score 1):

The part of the notes of Vistoli on fibered cats in FGA explained can be read without knowing AG (there are parts which do refer to schemes, but these can be ignored). Also, I don't believe the part of Grothendieck's TDTE introducing fibered cats refers to schemes, so you can read this as well. However, without schemes, these things become hard to motivate, so for motivation, you could maybe read Noohi's foundations of topological stacks.

Answer (score 1):

There is also an entirely logical/category theoretic motivation for fibered categories, as visible here: http://www.mathematik.tu-darmstadt.de/~streicher/FIBR/FibLec.pdf