# What is a (co)fibration in category theory

Tags: category-theory, fibration

Coming from a computer science background, I have some working knowledge on category theory but none in algebraic topology. I see many definition involves some homotopy theory which I completely have no clue, yet I see many applications of fibrations in category theory and/or related topics (e.g. a random paper: https://dlicata.wescreates.wesleyan.edu/pubs/lsr17multi/lsr17multi-ex.pdf).

My questions are: what is a (co)fibration in categorical terms? What is the intuition of (co)fibrations in categorical settings?

Comment: I think [this](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/discrete+fibration)  gives the definitions that are referenced in the paper from a brief search through the paper.

Comment: @jgon but what's the difference between the discrete and nondiscrete ones?

Comment: @JasonHu This isn’t a good MSE question, since the answer should be a whole article.

Comment: @KevinArlin I understand your point but still a good existing introductory article or other resources, or a personal understanding would help. somehow I need to decipher people's choice of words, right?

Comment: @JasonHu A “non-discrete” fibration is a Grothendieck fibration, which you can find an intro to on the nLab as well. There should be some references on those articles. “Cofibration” is not as much used in category theory though it sometimes means “opfibration”.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1812490/in-category-theory-what-is-a-fibration-and-why-should-i-care-about-them) would help.